# FlatList Typescript error missing return type on function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Im trying to use a interface on the renderItem={({ item }) from flatlist, but whenever i try im getting the same error.

"Missing return type on function. eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)"

How can i type that?

```
  export function Notifications(): JSX.Element {

interface INotificationsProps {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  link: string;
}

interface INotificationsObject {
  event: INotificationsProps[];
}

      let datas: INotificationsObject = {
        event: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Missa de Santo Antônio',
            description:
              'Si osculantur puorhuus aut unexem tuam osculun, non dico qued omnia quan sunt hominiset sic non tangebur, si aut ex eis meriatur.',
            link: 'www.google.com.br',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Bazar Beneficente',
            description:
              'Si osculantur puorhuus aut unexem tuam osculun, non dico qued omnia quan sunt hominiset sic non tangebur, si aut ex eis meriatur.',
            link: 'www.google.com.br',
          },
        ],
      };
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <FlatList
            data={datas.event}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ContainerNotifications>
                <TitleNotification>{item.title}</TitleNotification>
                <DescriptionNotification>
                  {item.description}
                </DescriptionNotification>
    
                <SeeMore>Ver mais</SeeMore>
              </ContainerNotifications>
            )}
          />
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the argument list is where you can put the return type for the function.

```
({ item }): JSX.Element => (<ContainerNotifications>...)
```